# Panel Drag and Drop not working in winForms Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a winForm application using c#.NET. On the form i have placed a panel, and i have 2 methods :

```
    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e){
    //some code here
    }
    private void panel1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //some code here
    }
```

Whenever i run the program in debug mode(x64), i cannot seem to hit panel1_DragDrop method. I have also tried using a breakpoint , but it is also not being hit.
I have put property AllowDrop=true for this panel, but still nothing is happening. 
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Did you check the properties of the panel and the events it is referring to?

Comment: Yes i did, and it is working for Panel click idk why its not doing the same for dragdrop

Comment: What is being dropped? Where does it come from? We may need to see more code..

Comment: i want drag and drop a certain area on panel, so that i can get the coordinates and create a rectangle on the panel

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `DragEnter` event :

```
    private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
       {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
       }

    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
      {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        if (Path.GetExtension(files[0]).ToLower() == ".pdf")//jpg,bmp,docx,....
        {
            //Code
        }
      }
```

Also please check if your application isn't running as another user privilege like **Run as Administrator**.
 ["Run as Administrator" prevents drag and drop working.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cba0e9b1-25f8-40e5-a888-1435d604f68d/quotrun-as-administratorquot-prevents-drag-and-drop-working?forum=w7itprosecurity)

Comment: i am actually trying to  drag this panel inside my form. I tried this method. None of these methods are being hit even when i use breakpoints.